# SpringBootTest,GrpcCleanupRule and @Autowired

Tags: grpc

I'm trying to use GrpcCleanupRule for gRPC related tests.
This is the part of the code for the test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SaveTest {

@Rule
public final GrpcCleanupRule grpcCleanup = new GrpcCleanupRule();

@Autowired
private FileUtils fileUtils;

@Test
public void saveGrpcTest() throws IOException {
    String filePath = fileUtils.getFilePath(USER_ID, PROJECT_ID, TASK_ID, ELEMENT_ID, LIGHT_PATH_ID_01, Constant.FILE_OPR_READ);

    String serverName = InProcessServerBuilder.generateName();
    grpcCleanup.register(InProcessServerBuilder
            .forName(serverName).directExecutor().addService(new GrpcStorageServiceImpl()).build().start());
    StorageServiceGrpc.StorageServiceBlockingStub blockingStub = StorageServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(
        grpcCleanup.register(InProcessChannelBuilder.forName(serverName).directExecutor().build()));
    StorageReply reply =
            blockingStub.saveHfm(PersistentHfmRequest.newBuilder()
                    .setUserId(USER_ID)
                    .setProjectId(PROJECT_ID)
                    .setTaskId(TASK_ID)
                    .setElementId(ELEMENT_ID)
                    .setLightPathId(LIGHT_PATH_ID_08)
                    .build());
    assertEquals("Hello test name", reply.getMessage());
}
}
```

This is the part of the code for the gRPC serve.

```
public class GrpcStorageServiceImpl extends StorageServiceGrpc.StorageServiceImplBase {

@Resource
private FileUtils fileUtil;

@Override
public void save(PersistentHfmRequest request, StreamObserver<StorageReply> responseObserver) {
    HarmonicFieldMode hfm = request.getHfm();
    String filePath = fileUtil.getFilePath();
    // ...
}
}
```

The FileUtil in the test class is working,but is null in the gRPC server.
Then I try another test.This is the part of the code for the test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SendMessageTest {

    @Rule
    public final GrpcCleanupRule grpcCleanup = new GrpcCleanupRule();

    @Autowired
    private SseServiceImpl sseService;

    @Test
    public void sendMessage() throws IOException {
      sseService.createConnect("abc001");
}
}
```

This is the part of the code for the gRPC serve.

```
public class SseServiceImpl extends MessageServiceGrpc.MessageServiceImplBase implements ISseService {
 @Autowired
    private RedisUtil redisUtil;
 public SseEmitter createConnect(String userId) throws IOException {
if (redisUtil.hasKey(userId)) {
//...
}
}
```

The RedisUtil is working.

What should I do to complete gRPC testing?